# warning: format string contains '\0' within the string body [-Wformat]

Tags: c, string, system, quoting

I've got a `system()` command inside my code which uses awk. I can't figure out how to fix an issue with`\x00` hexadecimal values. Apparently they need to be terminated differently, but that's beyond the realm of what I know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char command[128];
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "awk '{ gsub (/\xAB\x00\x00\xBC/,\"\xBC\x00\x00\xAB\") ; print }' %s", argv[1]);
    system(command);

}
```

Warnings/Errors:

```
>  test.c:8:56: warning: format string contains '\0' within the string body [-Wformat]
>  snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "awk '{ gsub (/\xAB\x00\xBC/,\"\xBC\x00\x00\xAB\") ; print }' %s", argv[1]);
>  /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:57:62: note: expanded from macro 'snprintf'
>  __builtin___snprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                              ^
  1 warning generated.
  sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
  sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

<sub>Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find any relevant info though in the search on how to fix this,  thanks...</sub>

Comment: it works from the command-line, although i don't need to escape the `"` like in `C`

Comment: Replace every instance of `\x` with `\\x`.

Comment: I use like this in terminal `awk '{ gsub (/\xAB\x00\x00\xBC/,"\xBC\x00\x00\xAB") ; print }' file`

Comment: You can't have a null character inside a C string. \x00 represents the null character, same as \0. However, you can put \x00 in your C string (as in backslash, ex, zero, zero, not as in a null character) if you escape the backslash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the C string literal `"\xAB"`. This string literal contains one byte, not 4. Similarly, `"\x00"` is a string literal that contains one byte which is a null byte. Clang warns you about that because a null byte ends the C string — every character after it will be ignored by library functions such as `snprintf`.

In your awk code, there's an awk string literal, surrounded by double quotes. You wrote `…\"\xBC\x00\x00\xAB\"…`, with backslashes in front of the double quotes, because otherwise the double quotes would be interpreted as ending the C string literal. Similarly, if you want to end up with a backslash in the awk code (more precisely, in the shell command), you need another backslash in front of it. In other words, you need to double your backslashes.

```
snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "awk '{ gsub (/\\xAB\\x00\\x00\\xBC/,\"\\xBC\\x00\\x00\\xAB\") ; print }' %s", argv[1]);
```

Beware that there's another quoting problem with your program: it interprets its argument as a snippet of shell code, not as a file name. The two only coincide if the file name doesn't contain any shell special characters. For example, `./your_program Jack.txt` will work, but not `./your_program "O'Leary.txt"`. To make it work, you need to massage the argument to protect shell special characters.

(Another problem is that you don't check whether `snprintf` succeeds. It could overflow — you should dynamically allocate the necessary size based on the length of the argument (don't forget to account for the extra quoting if the argument contains special characters).)

Comment: Thank you! For the suggestions I will implement the checks for the file name as you mentioned. Amazing how running one shell command can end up being not so simple as it seemed to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of characters `'\'`, `'x'`, `'0'`, `'0'` within a C string literal represents a single `char` with numeric value zero.  Thus, the `char` arrays represented by the two string literals `"\x00"` and `"\0"` have the same size and contents: two `char`s (including the terminator), both zero.  When used as C strings, both are equivalent to an empty string because the zero character at index zero serves as a string terminator.

Your compiler is warning you that the string literal you pass to `snprintf()` contains internal null bytes (it has two, in fact), which likely will lead to it not being interpreted as you intended.  If you mean the `\xhh` sequences in the string to be taken as sequences of four literal characters, then you must double the backslashes:

```
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "awk '{ gsub (/\\xAB\\x00\\x00\\xBC/,\"\\xBC\\x00\\x00\\xAB\") ; print }' %s", argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this really helped me :)